# How to use OCMockito to check the value inserted into UserDefault

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmockito

I am staring to use **OCMockito** for Unit Testing. Right now I am using it to mock a `UserDefaults`(through dependency injection).

I can control what is returned back by:
  `[given([mockUserDefaults objectForKey:@"some key"]) willReturn:@"a value I want"];`

Now my question is: How do I check what values the user set to the mock `UserDefaults`?

for example, if user issued:
  `[self.userDefaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:"example"];`

How do I get the `date` back from the mock `userDefaults`?

Comment: I tried directly using `[self.userDefaults objectForKey:@"example"]`, but the result is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OCMockito doesn't have a way (yet) to capture and return arguments. Instead, each argument must satisfy an OCHamcrest matcher. If no matcher is specified, then `equalTo` is assumed.

Testing `[NSDate date]` is generally not a good idea in unit tests, because you have no control over the date. But for the sake of example, here's a verification that the argument is *any* NSDate. (`sut` is the "system under test".)

```
[verify(sut.userDefaults) setObject:instanceOf([NSDate class]) forKey:@"example"];
```

So here, the first matcher is `instanceOf` to match any NSDate.

The second matcher is implicitly `equalTo(@"example)`

**Update:**

OCMockito 1.1.0 has a way to capture arguments, using MKTArgumentCaptor:

```
MKTArgumentCaptor *argument = [[MKTArgumentCaptor alloc] init];
[verify(sut.userDefaults) setObject:[argument capture] forKey:@"example"];
```

You can retrieve the captured argument with `[argument value]`, or an array of all captured arguments with `[argument allValues]`.

Comment: Thank you@Jon! I have been also following screencasts on [Quality Coding](http://qualitycoding.org/). They are very helpful for us new starters!

Comment: How about OCMock? Does it capture and return?

Comment: OCMockito 1.1.0 adds a way to capture arguments.